# LDAP Authentication with Python Flask - keeping password out of server memory

Tags: javascript, python, security, authentication, ldap

Has anyone implemented, using Python Flask (or otherwise..), a user authentication system where users are authenticated to your web application against LDAP but where the passwords are never actually passed to the server?

I can successfully authenticate my users to my Flask apps by taking their LDAP user/pass (via standard implementation of Flask-WTForms - getting password back to server from client) and using the python-ldap module, but the fact that there seems to be no clean manual way to clear their password from memory in Python, after the LDAP binding, means that their password lingers on the server for some undisclosed amount of time.

My thoughts are that there must be some way to have the client (likely via JS) perform the LDAP binding without ever passing the password to the server.

Has anyone done something like this?  Maybe something with JWTs?  Ideally, I'm looking for a module or library here, as this must be something that is commonly needed.

Comment: The user should never have to enter their AD username/password into a UI. Your server code should get current AD user and pass that up. Otherwise it wouldnt be called single sign on, and there would be no point in using LDAP for authentication.

Comment: You're looking for SASL/GSSAPI. Where the users client authenticates against the AD and then pass a token to the web-server - that the web server can use to impersonate the user. If you're actually looking to **sign in** and get the token, yea you need to supply the username+password, but in that case it's debatable if there's ever a secure way of doing it. Python has nothing like "secure string" or similarly that guarantees  that nothing is kept in memory. Much of this functionality is in the browser and webserver tho, so not so much flask/django/python.

Comment: @Torxed but isn't the point of authenticating with LDAP so that the user never has to manually log in (ex. typing in username/pass)? That completely defeats the purpose of SSO.

Comment: It is, that's what GSSAPI and SASL is for. It will tell the client browser to authenticate directly with the AD and then pass the token to the web server that can use that token to do stuff against the AD without the need for a user password. @IsaacVidrine. The only exception to this rule, is if you're setting up something that administrates a users account remotely where the client can't access the AD directly or if the web-server software can't handle the SSO protocols. Either way, supporting SSO and passing around a token **is the way to go** :)

Comment: @Torxed thank you. for being helpful instead of snarky.